# how to create coordinator job to run last one month jobs one time i.e date based?

Tags: hadoop, oozie, cloudera-cdh, oozie-coordinator

I want to create a coordinator job which should run monthly once but day by day.i.e it should run end of the month, same day it self it should all days of the month.

for example : august month. it should run end of the august month(2016-08-31), but at the same day it self it should run all days of the month i.e. 2016-08-01,2016-08-02...2016-08-31 on the same day i.e (2016-08-31 it self all 31 days ).

I need to get day value dynamically  for my action node...with the help of coordinator job i should able to get day value .

please help me on this. Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can run that the start of the month and run on all the days in the previous month. In you Example your WF will run at `1/9` on `2016-08-*`

If you want to use the `done-flag` you need to use the [EL Function daysInMonth](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a6.6.3._coord:daysInMonthint_n_EL_Function_for_Synchronous_Datasets) so your `input-events` would be something like:

```
<input-events>
        <data-in name="input" dataset="mydataset">
          <start-instance>${coord:current( -(coord:daysInMonth(0) - 1) )}</start-instance>
          <end-instance>${coord:current(0)}</end-instance>
        </data-in>
      </input-events>
```